# Probability in playing cards

Tags: probability

I came across a question in which we have to find the probability of getting either a heart card or a queen card when one card is taken at random from a well-shuffled deck of 52 playing cards.

I thought that 'either' being used here might imply that the card can be a heart card or a queen card, but it can't be both (i.e., the queen of hearts). Extending this, we get the probability to be equal to 15/52 (I omitted the queen of hearts from the number of favourable outcomes). Can this be taken as an answer? Or should I include the queen of hearts so that I get the answer as 16/52?

Comment: To be clear, this is a matter of language and convention and so could be said to be ambiguous.  A well written question would have avoided the issue entirely and made it clear.  The standard convention in mathematical contexts is for this to include the queen of hearts unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say for your question exactly (depends on the intention of the question poser), but typically in math when we say $A$ OR $B$, that means we're looking at the set of events that are in $A$, along with the set of events that are in $B$. In particular, it is ok if the event is in both $A$ and $B$. In other words, we are including events in the intersection (in this case, cards that are a heart and a queen).

Maybe this Venn diagram will help clear things up:

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that the question is ambiguous?

Comment: No it's not ambiguous. I just mean that sometimes the person writing the question might have a misunderstanding of what OR means.

Comment: In this case, yes, we should include the Queen of hearts

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.